# Java: What happens to the supposed-to-be initialized members when passing a value to their object at creation time?

Tags: java, constructor, initialization

This question is more about having a proper Java program construction.
I was wondering: What happens to the

```
public Clazz { 
   this.someClazz = new SomeClazz(); 
}  //initialization

Clazz x = y;
```

Is the above constructor gets executed, or is it skipped, and someClazz memberget a new value right away?

Comment: It's not really about "having a proper Java program construction" - it's about understanding fundamental aspects of the language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to distinguish between variables, objects and references.

The values of `x` and `y` are not objects - they're just references. The assignment operator *just* copies the value from the expression on the right to the variable on the left. So in your case, it copies the value of `y` into `x`... at that point, the values of both variables refer to the same object. No constructors or any other members get called - it's *just* copying a value. So for example:

```
// Assuming appropriate methods...
x.setFoo("new foo");
System.out.println(y.getFoo()); // Would print "new foo"
```

However, the two *variables* are still independent:

```
x.setFoo("new foo");
x = new Clazz();
x.setFoo("yet another foo");
System.out.println(y.getFoo()); // Would print "new foo"
```

Here, after the second line, the values of `x` and `y` refer to *different* objects, so calling `x.setFoo()` doesn't change the value of `foo` within the object that `y` refers to.

Comment: WOW! It's Mr. Jon Skeet himself answering my humble question :D I've always seen your thorough answers at other questions and admired you knowledge in programming : ) Anyways back to the question, thank you for your answer it made things much clearer for me now. By the way, There are just too many out there, do you recommend a good book on Java?

Answer (score 1):

Here in code snippet `Clazz x = y;` ,  you are not making any new object. You are just telling that, now, `x` reference will refer to that object which `y` is pointing to.

When you have created an object `y`, `Clazz y = new Clazz();` , then `y` starting referring to an object that is in heap.

```
y--------------------------> Obj1
```

and after `Clazz x = y;`

```
x-----> y---------> Obj1
```

that is actually something like following

```
x--->Obj1<----y
```

Here, since no new object has not been created, therefore, no constructor will be called,
and no member initialization would occur, i.e, `this.someClazz = new SomeClazz();` wont be executed.

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answers : ) If I read your answer first, I would have chosen it.

Answer (score 0):

In you code you are not creating a new intance of your class, you simply assigning the reference of `y` to your variable `x`